# Dynamic statement in a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to run a trigger on Oracle to update several fields of a table with data coming from another table, after an update event.  I want to use dynamic SQL statements.  Both tables have a lot of fields in common, different by a prefix.  The use of "execute immediate" works only if the field I'm updating is explicit.  As soon as I use a variable for the field name, it doesn't work.  Any idea?

```
Here is the code :
create or replace TRIGGER AF_UPDATE_PRODUCT_REQUEST 
AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUCT_REQUEST 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (old.PREQCOMPLETE=1)

DECLARE


product_fieldname varchar2(100);
counter number(1);
tata number(3);
old_value VARCHAR2(500);
new_value VARCHAR2(500);

BEGIN
 tata:=0;
  FOR c1 in (SELECT column_name from user_tab_columns WHERE     table_name='PRODUCT_REQUEST')
  LOOP
    old_value:=to_char(:old.PREQDESC2);
    new_value:=to_char(:new.PREQDESC2);
    IF old_value<>new_value THEN
      product_fieldname:=replace(c1.column_name,'PREQ','PU');
      select count(*) into counter from user_tab_columns WHERE     table_name='PRODUCT' and column_name=product_fieldname;
      IF counter=1 THEN
        tata:=tata+1;
        /*execute immediate 'update product set '|| product_fieldname ||'=:new.'|| c1.column_name ||' where pupname=:old.preqpname';*/
        /*execute immediate 'update product set pushelflife=16 where pupname=:d3' using :old.preqpname;*/
        IF product_fieldname='PUSHELFLIFE' THEN
          /*execute immediate 'update product set pushelflife=:d2 where pupname=:d3' using 15,:old.preqpname;*/
          execute immediate 'update product set :d1=:d2 where pupname=:d3' using product_fieldname,15,:old.preqpname;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass in object or column names as bind variables to a dynamic SQL statement.  You would have to construct the dynamic SQL statement using those column names.  Something like

```
execute immediate 'update product ' ||
                  '   set ' || product_fieldname || ' = :val '
                  ' where pupname = :key'
           using 15, :old.preqpname
```

Comment: I tried that, but it fails.  Reading more about it, it seems not possible to do inside the trigger.  Maybe a function can do the trick.  My goal is the following : I have 180 fields in the product request table, in common with 180 fields in the product file.  I would like to find an easy way to update the fields in the product file if the matching product request table record is updated after the product creation is complete.

Comment: Define "it fails".  Why are you storing the same data in two different tables if you want the data to match in the first place?  If you are really determined to violate normalization, you would be better off writing dynamic SQL to generate the trigger code and using static SQL within the generated trigger.  It is still possible to use dynamic SQL inside a trigger but you can't dynamically reference attributes of the `:old` and `:new` pseudorecords so that does not tend to be particularly helpful.

Comment: I agree that the structure of our tables was not wise.  PRODUCT_REQUEST and PRODUCT should have been one table with a  flag saying that the product is available (PRODUCT) or not (PRODUCT_REQUEST). Basically, I don't succeed to make the update work if the name of the field I try to update is a variable and not a valid field name for that table.  PRODUCT_REQUEST does not have exactly the same fields than PRODUCT but has a lot in common.  I try to create a trigger to update the common fields from one table to the other if a user modifies these fields after the product is created in PRODUCT.